# Travis-CI run failed, but passed locally

Tags: node.js, yeoman, travis-ci

I'm learning Yeoman & I've made a generator for ionic-framework

[Source Code Here](https://github.com/DotHide/generator-hionic)

When I run `$ npm test`, It works fine locally.

But when I pushed it to GitHub, the Travis-CI always failed.

I try to set timeout of gulp-mocha to **20000ms**, but it still doesn't work.

Is there anyone knows the reason why? Thx.

Comment: Look into travis output what the concrete problem is. Or add the link of your travis build here.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the reason.

It's version of node. **5.10.1** works

Comment: You may specify node version to use in .travis.yml config.